# How can I add a custom script to footer of login page?

Tags: login, wp-login-form, footer

I need to add this:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.janrainContent').css('border','0px');jQuery('.janrainContent').css('width','252px');jQuery('#janrainAuthReturnExperience').css('width','252px');
});
</script>
```

Right before the closing tag of the Wordpress login page's `</body>` tag.
How do you do it?
Would I use a combination of `login_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_scripts` and set `$in_footer` to true? I'm not entirely sure how I would do that either...

Answer (score 6):

This is what ended up working for me:
Put your script into a .js file and then:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script' );

function enqueue_my_script( $page ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'http://domain.com/path/myjs-file.js', null, null, true );
}
```

Comment: Optionally use this to load jQuery since your script depends on it:

```wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'http://domain.com/path/myjs-file.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );```